# Toggling the infobox in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am working in google maps and successfully implemented the **infobox plugin** of google maps.Now my concern is that how can we know that the **infobox for a marker is in open state or not**. so that I can toggle it on click of the marker...

```
var locations = [
        //this is array of arrays
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),{
        disableDefaultUI : true,
        zoom : 12,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(defaultLatitude,defaultLongitude),
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });


    var mapcode,myOptions;

    for (var i = 0,len = locations.length; i < len; i++) {
        var marker = add_marker(locations[i][1],locations[i][2],locations[i][3],'this is title',locations[i][0]);
        allMarkers.push(marker);
        marker.setMap(map);
    };

    function add_marker(lat,lng,icn,title,box_html) {

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
            position : new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
            map : map,
            icon : icn
        }); 

        mapcode = '<this is the code of infobox to show>';

        myOptions = {
             //options of the infobox...bla bla
        };

        var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            ib.open(map, marker);
        });   
        return marker;
    }
```

I am new in **google maps** so may be I am missing some very small stuff...thanks in advance....
Ankur

Comment: Why don't you just set a global variable on opening a box and reset it on closing?

Comment: Because there are more than 50 markers and all of them have different content to show so in order to get that i used different object of infobox ....

Comment: Then you could use an array of bools. Or attach a field to box object containing its state. Or (what I personally find the best solution, but maybe it's a bit late to change) use one box and change its anchor and content  dynamically (only viable if only one box can be open, in this case you don't have to worry about closing others manually)

Comment: Can you please give some url or blog link that implemented this

Comment: Which solution would you like to see implemented? paste some code of how you create markers and I will modify it for you in an answer.

Comment: I have added the code as well

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15322/discussion-between-ankur20us-and-slawekwin)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you just need one infobox open at any time you could do it like that:

```
    var ib = new InfoBox();
    ib.isOpen = false;
    function add_marker(lat,lng,icn,title,box_html) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        map : map,
        icon : icn
    }); 

    mapcode = '<this is the code of infobox to show>';

    myOptions = {
         //options of the infobox...bla bla
    };
    marker.ibOptions = myOptions;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        ib.setOptions(marker.ibOptions);
        ib.open(map, marker);
        ib.isOpen = true;
    });   
    return marker;
}
```

If you do it like that you need to reset flag every time you call ib.close() with ib.isOpen = false; (you didn't specify in what situations do you close the box)

In case you need multiple boxes to be opened:

```
function add_marker(lat,lng,icn,title,box_html) {

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position : new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        map : map,
        icon : icn
    }); 

    mapcode = '<this is the code of infobox to show>';

    myOptions = {
         //options of the infobox...bla bla
    };

    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
    ib.isOpen = false;
    marker.ib = ib;

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        marker.ib.open(map, marker);
        marker.ib.isOpen = true;
    });   
    return marker;
}
```

And again if you ever call allMarkers[...].ib.close() you will need to reset the flag with allMarkers[...].ib.isOpen = false;

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can check if an infowindow is already opened in the click event listener of Google maps. You can check it like this:

```
var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    if(ib)
        ib.close();
    marker.ib.open(map, marker);
}
```

I hope this fixes your issue.